# Two ajax jquery call in the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need your help 
I have to call 2 ajax in the same function...I have this code:

```
$('#client_id').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
          url: './service/jsonNote.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: 'query=' + $('#client_id').val(),
          dataType: 'JSON',
          async: true
      })
    .done(function(data) {
        var jsProducts = data;
        $.ajax({
          url: './service/jsonNoteNomi.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: 'query=' + $('#client_id').val(),
          dataType: 'JSON',
          async: true
        })
        .done(function(data) {
          alert(data);
        })
        .fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
      })
      .always(function() {
        alert( "complete" );
      });
    });
});
```

And it alert "Error". What is wrong? Can you help me, please?

Comment: the ajax requests are fine. Here's a fiddle showing them working. http://jsfiddle.net/zLedjj8x/. Seems you're just simply getting an error back from your server which is why you hit the fail function. check the network to insure the request is successful

Comment: But in my Firebug I see in console that it response with datas...

Comment: I solved...I had to change the DataType of the second one because I didn't have Json answer but simply text.

Comment: Put that in an answer so we know this question is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved...I had to change the DataType of the second one because I didn't have Json answer but simply text.